# How to download files in colab like a download manager

Tags: python, curl, google-colaboratory, wget

Can someone please tell me how to download files in colab like a download manager.
I know the standard transfer methods of wget and curl but they don't download the file in parts. I want to download a file in parts like download managers do. I want to download a big file very fast but I cannot (using wget or curl)because the file's server has bandwidth limit of 1MBps. If i am able to download it like a download manager, the file will be downloaded in multiple parts such that the bandwidth limit will be bypassed and I will be able to download the file very fast. Is there any way to download like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know if does met condition

> download it like a download manager

but if your main aim is to shorten download time you might give a try [aria2](https://aria2.github.io/). It has `aria2c` CLI, example of download using 2 connections per host is given as follows

```
aria2c -x2 http://a/f.iso
```

You need to test it (possibly with different setting) to see if does provide rapid enough download for your use case.